# Uploading app for beta testing iTunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app for a client which needed some small updates, so I've amended those and I'm ready to upload to iTunes connect for beta testing before going live. The app already has a record in iTunes connect as this is a revision of the app. I have archived the app, and it has validated (confirmed with the large green tick). I'm unsure now if I need to do any more to get it onto iTunes connect. Do I click 'Upload to App Store' or will it appear on iTunes connect now that it has validated?

Comment: Yes, upload it to iTunes Store. Then, go to TestFlight section and select the version to test. It will notify all test users every time a new version build of that version is available.

Comment: So this will not get published to the store? Just iTunes connect to clarify?

Comment: @JonathanLockley yes it will not be published on the store, just uploaded to itunes

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to click `Upload to App Store` to make it available in the itunes connect

To upload the build to the itunes connect there is two options

- Upload it from the xcode , `Upload to App Store`
- From Application loader which comes with Xcode, Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> Application loader, here you can use same credentials of itunes connect and select a build to upload

When you click on the App Store select the first option upload to app store

After it is upload in the test flight it will be directly available to your internal testers it will not go for submission/live, for that you have to select particular build and start submission manually

For more information regarding this you can check docs for it

[Apple Doc:Beta testing with testflight](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html)
[Apple Doc: Distribute your app with testflight](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight.html) 
[Ray wenderlich Testflight tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial)